# Object detection training: partial objects and empty training images

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, object-detection

I am currently trying to detect objects (actually only 1 class) in large images (4000 x 4000 px) using the TensorFlow Object Detection API and a Faster RCNN model.

Since these are too large to be used in training and detection directly (on my hardware), I crop the images into overlapping sub-images of 500 x 500 px. In general this is working quite well but I sometimes get false positives with a very high score (> 99%) and my guess is that I can still improve the learning strategy.

So I have two questions:

1. How should I handle objects that are only partially inside a 500 x 500 px training image? So far, I only use objects that are fully inside the image area for training. But I was wondering whether the results might improve if I also accept objects that are e.g. overlapping 50% with a cropped image. Or would the results get worse?
2. What should I do with cropped sub-images that do not contain the object at all? Should I still add them to the training set and will the framework use these as negative examples? Or is it better to exclude them?

Answer (score 1):

For my experience, and from dataset examples available in Tensorflow, you get a better trained model if you include objects not only fully inside the image area, but even objects overlapping cropped images. This is to avoid overfitting.

Comment: Thanks. I started trying this using a threshold, i.e. only objects that are overlapping with the cropped image more than 80 % (area) should be used for training. But testing is a bit slow since training takes some time.